# What is the optimum number of sqls run in batch?

Tags: oracle, jdbc, batch-file

I am trying to load the data in Oracle server remotely. I am doing "executeBatch()" for every 50 sqls that are added in batch. (thru JDBC)

What is the optimum number of sqls run in batch? Is it unlimited?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quoted from [oracle documentation](http://www.oracle.com/technology/products/ias/toplink/doc/1013/main/_html/optimiz010.htm)

> - If you are using parameterized SQL (you configure your Login by calling
>     Login method bindAllParameters), the
>     maximum batch writing size is the
>     number of statements to batch
>     (default: 100).
> - If you are using dynamic SQL, the maximum batch writing size is the size
>     of the SQL string buffer in characters
>     (default: 32000).

There's no such thing as an "universal optimal value".

Each situation has its optimal value, which depends on a lot of things (including the probability a statement might fall, the average time taken per statement, the importance of the timing in your specific business situation, etc.)